# Running Nextjs App and getting err_connection_refused

Tags: reactjs, next.js, localhost

So, I'm trying to learn Nextjs. I followed all the instructions on the getting started page, but when I navigate to http://localhost:3000, I get the Err_Connection_Refused message.

What I did:
`npx create-next-app myproject --use-npm`

I then get a success message. Then I typed `cd myproject`, then `npm run dev`.

I don't get any errors. Instead, I get another success message `ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000`

Navigating to either of these urls just gives me an err_connection_refused message.

What's even weirder is that I can run react apps with no problem, but I can't run Nextjs at all.
I've tried using yarn and I get the same error.

P.S, I'm not touching the source code at all. I'm just following the getting started instructions and hitting these roadblocks.

Comment: you can try with npx create-next-app@latest appname, hope this way you can run your app.

Comment: I've done this too. Didn't work either.